# extract html templates in js tree with brunch compiler

Tags: angularjs, brunch

I have an AngularJS project that I moved to brunch recently where all the templates are stored in side the javascript tree.

example:

```
js/
-- main/
----main.js
----main.html
--sub/
----sub,js
----sub.html
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to configure Brunch.io to extract the html files from the js tree and publish them under public/

As a workaround I copied the js tree in assets and removed all the js files.

I'd like to keep the templates with the js files if possible.

Comment: i have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put stuff in directory `assets` e.g. `app/assets` -- it will be simply copied to `public`

https://github.com/brunch/brunch/tree/stable/docs#basics

Comment: Thanks, that's how I am using it now:
'As a workaround I copied the js tree in assets and removed all the js files.' 

I was hoping there was a way to get brunch to select files from a folder structure using a regex to copy to a destination. Like joinTo functions but just for copying